# forever -p /var/run/forever is ignored

Tags: node.js, forever

I'm trying to use the `-p` option to define where pid files are kept when starting forever with sudo. However, the pid files always show up in `/home/user/.forever` instead of `/var/run/forever`

edit: fyi I've switched to nodemon in dev and pm2 in production.

Comment: There is an open issue (#414) regarding the -p option, namely that it is being ignored.  See this link: https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/issues/414

Comment: The bug was closed, but it's still present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround was using the environment variable since -p didn't work for me either in my init.d script.

```
export FOREVER_ROOT=/var/run/forever
```

Hope this help you a bit until they release a version with a fix.

Was kinda mind puzzling since I tried to run forever with a forever system user without a home directory.